# Infragistics jquery grid with asp.net mvc 3.0 .net 4.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, infragistics

New to  all three.
I am trying to create sample grid. Basically I am following this: http://samples.infragistics.com/jquery/grid/filtering/

Here is my code:
(cshtml)

```
@using MyInfragistics.Models                
@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc

<div>
    @Html.Infragistics().Grid("grid1", Model.MyGridModel)
</div>
```

THe files are included are in _layout.cshtml:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link type="text/css" href='@Url.Content("~/Content/Styles/themes/min/ig/jquery.ui.custom.min.css")'  rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href='@Url.Content("~/Content/Styles/themes/base/ig.ui.min.css")'  rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Samples/combined/min/ig.ui.min.js")'/>
```

When I run the code, I get the error in the `ig.ui.min.js` file:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Comment: Try in jQuery-1.4.4 or newer :)

Comment: I tried with 1.5.1 also, same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would advice to take a look at [Blog Section](http://forums.infragistics.com/jquery/blogs/default.aspx) of the site. There are many blogs at the end of which there are runnable sample attached based on the blog theme. Try to modify any of the samples in the blogs which is more closer to your scenario.